# Rotate 90 degrees clockwise the scaleLabel (no ticks or labels) on a Chart.js line chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

How can I rotate 90 degrees clockwise the display of scaleLabel on the yAxis? Not the ticks or labels but the single element which is usually on the left side of the yAxis. In this example, containing the string: `labelString:'My Label'`

```
 var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel:{
          display:true,
          labelString:'My Label'
        },
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq57fxjp/

Comment: The ticks on yAxes are able to read the properties `maxRotation` and `minRotation`. How something similar can be achieved for the scaleLabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired effect by commenting out the line

```
rotation = isLeft ? -0.5 * Math.PI : 0.5 * Math.PI;
```

in the source code.

Comment: Feature request here - https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5513